# Downloading a PDF on Dropbox to a phone from a given URI in Base64 gives broken unreadable PDF

Tags: android, dropbox

I'm getting the URI of PDF's from different sources (local on the phone, Google drive etc) and for Dropbox I can read a byte array using the URI as input. But the PDF that I'm getting is not a valid PDF. Base64 is also not correct.

This is my URI:

content://com.dropbox.android.FileCache/filecache/a54cc030-e2e0-4ef5-8e72-0ac3269a16e1

```
val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(Uri.parse(uri))
val allText = inputStream.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
val base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(allText.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT)
```

allText content (snippet):

```
%PDF-1.3
%���������
4 0 obj
<< /Length 5 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >>
.
.
.
13025
%%EOF
```

When storing the allText content with .PDF extension doesn't work.

The format looks good, but when inserting base64Image in https://base64.guru/converter/decode/pdf it shows that it's not correct.

Original PDF content (snippet):

```
2550 4446 2d31 2e33 0a25 c4e5 f2e5 eba7
f3a0 d0c4 c60a 3420 3020 6f62 6a0a 3c3c
.
.
.
.
0a73 7461 7274 7872 6566 0a31 3330 3235
0a25 2545 4f46 0a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - *"I can read a byte array using the URI as input. But the PDF that I'm getting is not a valid PDF."*
> - *"When storing the `allText` content with .PDF extension doesn't work."*

You're reading the PDF input bytes (hex) and storing them into a wrong format (text).
For example, all valid PDF files are expected to begin with bytes `25 50 44 46`. Your `allText` content snippet starts with `%PDF` which is the converted ASCII/UTF text representation of those bytes.

**Problem:**
All this is fine because we can just convert the text characters back into their respective byte values, right? Nope, not all byte values can be correctly recovered **back from text** format.

example #1: can convert...

```
input bytes : 25 50 44 46
as text     : %  P  D  F
into bytes  : 25 50 44 46
```

example #2: cannot convert (original data is not recovered, because no text chars for such bytes)...

```
input bytes : 25 C4 E5 F2 E5 EB A7 F3 A0 D0
as text     : %  � � � �  � � � � � 
into bytes  : 25 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

[image]

**Solution:**

Try something like below. You want **the logic** as explained within the code comments...

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.InputStream

fun main(args: Array<String>) 
{
    //# setup access to your file...
    var inFile :InputStream = File("your-file-path-here.pdf")
    var fileSize :Int = File(path).length()

    //# read file bytes into a bytes Array...
    var inStream :InputStream = inFile.inputStream()
    var inBytes :ByteArray = inStream.readBytes()

    //# Make as String (of hex values)...
    //var hexString :String = ""
    val hexString = ""
    for (b in inBytes) { hexString = String.format("%02X", b) }

    //# check values as hex... should print: 25 
    //print(hexString) //could be long print-out for a big file

    //# Make Base64 string...
    val base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(inBytes)
}
```

> *"Base64 is also not correct."*

**(option 1)**

Try converting to Base64 the `hexString` in above example code (*note: now added as `val base64`*).

**(option 2)**

Directly read file bytes into a Base64 string with simple...

```
val bytes = File(filePath).readBytes()
val base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is my URI:

That is not a file.

```
val file = File(uri)
```

That is not how you use a `Uri`. Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.

Note that reading in the entire content, let alone converting it to Base64 in memory, may cause you to encounter `OutOfMemoryErrors`.

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer. But It doesn't work with the conversion yet.

Comment: @JimClermonts: A PDF is not text. Do not use `BufferedReader::readText`. [Read in the bytes](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/read-bytes.html).